# How to avoid undisplayed screens to re-render in react-native?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, rerender

In an react-native app, using react-navigation, screens that have been displayed stay mounted (which is normal with react-navigation).
But many of screens consume redux store data.
And when I update data in the store from one displayed page, others pages (not displayed) re-render. Causing performance issue.

Any help to stop those screens to re-render until they are displayed again ?
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-freeze

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.